# On an <Object data> page, getting one pages on_click event to trigger a method in another page within the <Object data> page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp-classic, window.location

I am converting an old classic ASP website to asp.net/C#. This weeks problem with the conversion involves
replacing frames. A webpage (parent) spawns a popup using window.open.I am triggering the popup from a button on a gridview that runs this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popup(url, Title){" "}
  {
    (popupwindow = window.open(
      url,
      Title,
      "status=no,menubar=no,width=1000,height=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes"
    ))
  }
</script>
```

That popup uses Frames (See example)

```
<frameset framespacing="0" border="1" frameborder="1" rows="36,*,0">
    <frame name="Header" scrolling="no" noresize="false" target="main" src="ContentModules/<%=fsHeader %>" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frameset cols="140,*">
          <frameset rows="*,27%">
              <frame name="Menu" target="main" src="ContentModules/<%= fsMenu %>" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
              <frame name="RevTable" src="ContentModules/<%= fsRevision %>">
          </frameset>
          <frame name="main" src="ContentModules/<%= fsMain %>" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" scrolling="yes" target="_self">
       </frameset>
</frameset>
```

This site needs to be HTML 5 compliant and work with I.E and Chrome. So far, I am able to do just that. However,
I cant use Frames and meet those objectives.

I replaced the frames with Object Data.

```
<div id="header" class="header">
    <object data="https://localhost:44365/HEADER.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>

<div id="main" class="row">

    <div id="column2" class="column left">
        <div id="left_top" class="left_top">
            <object data="https://localhost:44365/MainMenu.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
        </div>
        <div id="left_bottom" class="left_bottom">
            <object data="https://localhost:44365/RevTable.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column1" class="column right">
        <object data="https://localhost:44365/MAIN.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works great,  however, there is a problem that I cant figure out. We need to edit/save the MAIN Page. The button 
    to save or edit is on the HEADER page. I cant figure out how to get a click event on the HEADER page to run a saving method
    on the MAIN page.

In the original ASP version, they use an environmental variable to change the button text from EDIT to SAVE. 
They then use javascript to reload the entire popup so that it comes up in edit mode (or Save mode). I am not very knowledgeable on Javascript, but this seems an overhead heavy way of doing things.

```
function EditForm() {
  window.location =
    "/default.asp?windid=<%=windID%>&id=<%=id%>&ver=<%=ver%>&action=EDIT";
}
```

If the button was on the MAIN page, it would just be a simple on_click event. However, we have to duplicate the look and feel of the legacy
website. This means triggering an action on the MAIN page from an on-click event on the HEADER page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

@yob  Adding revised Code, erroring out with Unable to get property 'Content Window' of undefined or null reference.

VRVMAIN.aspx (The Parent Page with the < Object Data >  for Header.aspx and Main(default.aspx) Pages)

```
    function messageHandler(message) {
        console.log(" main page handler: ");
        var data = message["data"];
        console.log("             caller:" + (data["caller"] || ""));
        console.log("             caller:" + (data["data"] || ""));
        callMainPage(data);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false)
    }
    else {
        attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);
    }

    function callMainPage(data) {
        console.log(" Parent page(VRVMain.aspx) Calling Main(Default.aspx) Page");
        document.querySelector('[data="https://localhost:44365/VRView/Content/types/default.aspx"]').contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
    }
```

HEADER.aspx Page

```
    function callContainer(){
        console.log("calling container from header: ");
        var data = { "caller": "header", "data": 1234 };
        window.parent.postMessage(data, '*');
    }
```

Default.aspx (Main Page)

```
      function messageHandler(message){
         console.log ( " main page(default) handler: ");
         var data = message["data"];
         console.log ( "             caller:" + ( data["caller"]     ||""));
         console.log ( "             data:" + ( data["data"] ||""));
        callMainPage(data);
     }

         if (window.addEventListener) {
                 addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false)
         } 
         else 
         {
                 attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);           
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

since browser will not allow accessing object page (see blocked a frame from accessing a cross-origin frame), you could post a message to main page:
for example, in your header page:

```
    <html>
    <body>
            <div>
                    header
                    <a href="#" onclick="callMain()" >header click</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <div>start main</div><hr/>
                            <object data="main.html" type="text/html" width="100%" height="50%"></object>
                    <hr/><div>end main</div>
            </div>
            <script>
                    function callMain(){
                            console.log ( " calling main from header: ");
                            var data = {"caller":"header", "data":1234};
                            //this will not work - blocked a frame from accessing a cross-origin frame -> document.querySelector('[data="main.html"]').contentWindow.clickHandler(data);
                            //instead - post message 
                            document.querySelector('[data="main.html"]').contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
                    }
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

then, your main page (main.html) can listen for posted messages and process them:

```
    <html>
    <body>
            <div>
                main content
            </div>
            <script>
                    function messageHandler(message){
                            console.log ( " main page handler: ");
                            var data = message["data"];
                            console.log ( "             caller:" + ( data["caller"] ||""));
                            console.log ( "             caller:" + ( data["data"] ||""));
                        }

                    if (window.addEventListener) {
                            addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false)
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                            attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);           
                    }
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edited, based on additional comments...
If you have an "outer" container page, hosting header and main pages, then your header page needs to post a message to container page, which in turn, posts a message to main page:

for example, outer.html

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
        outer container

    </div>
    <div>
        <div>start header</div><hr/>
        <object data="header.html" type="text/html" width="100%" height="50%"></object>
        <hr/><div>end header</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>start main</div><hr/>
        <object data="main.html" type="text/html" width="100%" height="50%"></object>
        <hr/><div>end main</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function messageHandler(message){
            console.log ( " container page handler: ");
            var data = message["data"];
            console.log ( "             caller:" + ( data["caller"] ||""));
            console.log ( "             caller:" + ( data["data"] ||""));
            callMainPage(data);
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false)
        } else {
            attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);           
        }

        function callMainPage(data){
                document.querySelector('[data="main.html"]').contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and header page needs to post a message on click:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                header
                <a href="#" onclick="callContainer()" >header click</a>
            </div>
            <script>
                function callContainer(){
                    console.log ( " calling container from header: ");
                            var data = {"caller":"header", "data":1234};
                    window.parent.postMessage(data, '*');
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I am not a big Javascript guy, so I need to sit down and try your examples. I forgot to mention, The button changes text from SAVE to EDIT and vise versa depending on the state. When the page come up, it is in view mode,   and the button will say EDIT. When editing, the button would say SAVE.  The message from the HEADER page would need to communicate the state of the button (EDIT or SAVE). Not sure how I would handle the Button text change, Maybe Button On_Click would change the text ?

Comment: @pmcs - yes, button onclick changes button text, and communicates "view mode" to your main page.

Comment: Yob, why do have the MAIN page launching from the HEADER page ?                                    <div>
                    <div>start main</div><hr/>
                            <object data="main.html" type="text/html" width="100%" height="50%"></object>
                    <hr/><div>end main</div>
            </div>     All 4 pages are launched from a separate parent page.

Comment: @pmcs - this was just an example of how to "interact" between pages

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. Among other errors it says that it cant get the property 'Post Message'. Just to clarify, the HEADER and MAIN pages are both on the same object data HTML page that was launched as a popup from a parent page. Ive seen examples of messaging between parent and child pages, but this would be between two pages of the same child page. You sure this works ?

Comment: Thank You, That makes sense, You would message the on_click action on the header page back to the parent page, then the parent page would message to the Main page on  the same popup. I will give it a try later today. Thank You one again.

Comment: @pmcs, - yes your outer container serves as a "message bus"

Comment: I'm getting the data from the HEADER page to the Parent page. However, when it goes from the parent page to the Main page, it errors with "unable to get property 'ContentWindow' of undefined or null reference". Thought it might be the reference to the MAIN page so I tried it as fully qualified name as well, same error. Revised initial post to include  latest code with the error (Not sure how to post code using just the comment button).

Comment: another problem is that when I click on the button in the HEADER page, it opens the HEADER page in a new window. This shouldn't happen,

Comment: do you have *default.asp* or *default.aspx*? try using less complex selector, such as document.querySelector('[data^="default.asp" i]')...

Comment: Default.aspx, and Yes, I tried the short version. Works great communicating from Header to Parent, Its Parent to Main that seems to be the issue. I also dont understand why it opening the Header page in a full size window.

Comment: unless I see your complete code (you can try using jsfiddle.net to create a sample), not sure how I could help....what is your page URL and your querySelector?

Comment: I think I see the problem...  The Parent spawns 4 web pages into a popup (HEADER, MENU, REV, and MAIN). The MAIN page has a query string that determines what page is displayed in its place. In this case, the query element CID= 1 which means the page Default.aspx is displayed in its place. I don't think the parent knows about Default.aspx, only Main.aspx. therefor, the QuerySelector doesn't have a reference to Default.aspx. Not sure how I can get around this...

Comment: @pmcs - let's move this discussion to a chat -> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205523/on-an-object-data-page-getting-one-pages-on-click-event-to-trigger-a-method-in

Answer (score 0):

I thank you for your help, but I am going to close this as unworkable. Because the main page has a dynamic URL based on its query string, I don't think the Query Selector can get a reference to it. Even though the Parent knows it a Main.aspx, it dynamically changes to a different page.

Comment: you can check query string via window.location.search or output Request Uri from codebehind.